# How to debug problems in a C# Windows form application?

Tags: c#, winforms, addition, edit

I have to make a customer information system, which should have the following menu items:

- Add new customer
- Edit
- Delete
- Get the customer's information

There should be two forms: the signup form has to contain four textboxes- for the name, lastname, address and the email of the clients and a listbox where we should output the client's name and lastname after choosing the add menustriptool. Also when we add more information we should ***save it into a textfile***.

The second form should have a label where we should output the client information by reading it from the file.
And here is my code..

```
private void addToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("clients.txt", FileMode.Append))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                string name = textBox1.Text.Trim();
                string lastname = textBox2.Text.Trim();
                string address = textBox5.Text.Trim();
                string email = textBox7.Text.Trim();
                sw.WriteLine(name + "," + lastname + "," +address+"," + email);
    }
    }
}

    List<string> names = new List<string>();
    List<string> lastnames = new List<string>();
    List<string> adresses = new List<string>();
    List<string> emails = new List<string>();


private void editToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string newname = textBox1.Text;
        string newlastname = textBox2.Text;
        string newaddress = textBox5.Text;
        string newemail = textBox7.Text;
        names[listBox1.SelectedIndex] = newname;
        lastnames[listBox1.SelectedIndex] = newlastname;
        adresses[listBox1.SelectedIndex] = newaddress;
        emails[listBox1.SelectedIndex] = newemail;
        File.Delete("clients.txt");
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("clients.txt", FileMode.Append))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(names[i] + "," + lastnames[i]+ "," + adresses[i] + ","+ emails[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void deleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        names.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
        lastnames.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
        adresses.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
        emails.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
        File.Move("clients.txt", "../../clients1.txt");
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("clients.txt", FileMode.Append))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(names[i] + "," + lastnames[i] + "," + adresses[i] + "," + emails[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static string namec;
    public static string lnamec;
    public static string addrc;
    public static string emailc;
    private void getinfoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("clients.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                int br = 0;
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {

                    string line = sr.ReadLine();
                    string[] splitted = line.Split(',');
                    names.Add(splitted[0]); br++;
                    lastnames.Add(splitted[1]);
                    adresses.Add(splitted[2]);
                    emails.Add(splitted[3]);
                    for (int i = 0; i < br; i++)
                    {
                        namec = splitted[i];
                        lnamec = splitted[i + 1];
                        addrc = splitted[i + 2];
                        emailc = splitted[i + 3];
                        f2.Show();
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problems I have are the following:

1. I can't edit only one textbox. For example, I want to edit the client name, I write down the new name, but it deletes the other info.
2. Delete - I can delete only once. Then it shows error.
3. Get an info- I can get only the first clients info. When I choose the other clients, it outputs the first client info again.

Comment: @UweKeim: I think removing "tags" from titles is now discouraged, since it makes titles in the Hot Network Questions sidebar meaningless. Just rewrite titles so that "homemade tags" e.g. `[Winforms] [C#]` are merged into the title as a question in natural English. This one was fine, other than the please-help begging.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to fix your code directly but I can give you a few pointers that will make it a lot easier to do what you need.

**Holding information**

At the moment you are holding all your customer information in separate Lists, It works but it becomes annoying to deal with as you add more detail to it and makes saving slightly harder. Why not create a class that holds all the client information for you for example:

```
private class CustomerInformation
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

With this simple class you have all your customer information in one place, you then get this class out of a list instead of getting each string from an individual list `List<CustomerInformation> customer = new List<CustomerInformation>();`

**Saving**

So atm you are creating a text file manually and stepping through it then taking the lines that you saved and splitting them apart to reconstruct your data. You could use a [serialiser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656716.aspx) with will take the data that you have in memory and save it to disk without you programming how that works. That makes it less error prone as **it will adapt to the data that you give it** without change and makes your program **easier to maintain** as your requirements change. [The Binary Serializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.110).aspx) is fairly straightforward and has lots of good examples on the MSDN site.

With that new `CustomerInformation` class you now have you could simply ask it to [serialise](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5sbs8z9(v=vs.110).aspx) it for you and then when you need to load that data you point the serializer to the file and ask it to [deserialise](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b85344hz(v=vs.110).aspx) it for you turning it back into the data that you put in originally!

Side note: your saving code should probably be a separate method as it is used in multiple places and should be easy to maintain! :)

**Deleting**

If you look at your deleting code. What happens when you delete customer information? Does it still show the information of the customer that you just deleted? I'm guessing it does!

You need to check if your `listBox1.SelectedIndex` is out of bounds... so `if(listBox1.SelectedIndex < 0 || listBox1.SelectedIndex > customer.length)`, assuming that you changed your data to use the class from earlier. If that if statement is true you can't remove a List entry that you don't have.

Also since that customer data has just been deleted you should either **make the fields blank** or show someone else's data, preferably the former option. You probably also need to remove the customer from the ListBox since they don't exist any more.